# Angular - Does the number of injected modules affect performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say you have a module like so

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['coreModules']);
```

Does the number of modules contained in coreModules effect overall performance? That is to say, if it were to contain ten modules but only five are actually needed/used, will removing the extra five increase performance?

Obviously if they are surplus they should not be there in the first place, however just curious as to how much an impact it has!

Comment: There will *probably* be *some* overhead. However, the critical tradeoff is between making it easier to maintain for you and making it ***fast enough*** for the user. To get data on that last point: benchmark it!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, yes you should never have unnecessary modules injected into your app as goes by [YAGNI](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) because angular loads all the dependencies first up.